# Group datetime by month and year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Example dataframe:

```
date        count
2023-03-04  1
2022-07-29  3
2019-03-16  3
2019-03-14  1
2023-03-29  4
2022-07-17  1
```

I would like to group by month so my output is:

```
date        count
2019-03     4
2022-07     4
2023-03     5
```

I know I could use

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.month)['sales'].sum()
```

to group by month but I am unsure how to do month and year.

Comment: One option: `df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M'))['sales'].sum()`, there are several other options